# Как разбить строку на отдельные символы-элементы JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы, строки

Есть строка, к примеру:

```
str = "Шла Саша по шоссе и сосала сушку";
```

Как разбить строку наотдельные символы и обернуть в тег `<span>`

```js
string = $(".str").text();
str = string.split('');
$.each(str, function(i) {
  $(".str").append('<span class="style">'+str[i]+'</span>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="str">Шла Саша по шоссе и сосала сушку</div>
```

Попробовал вот так но не работает, и как заменить после перебора текущий элемент  `<div class="str">Шла Саша по шоссе и сосала сушку</div>`
на преобразованный

Comment: Попробуйте [этот код](http://jsfiddle.net/rvqghy0r/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно способ не лучший, но рабочий и ясный. Разделяем текст с помощью [`split("")`](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods), затем бежим по всем элементам через [`forEach`](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-iteration), создаем элементы через `document.createElement`, в `innerHTML` пишем содержимое, а с помощью `appendChild` добавляем к нужному, к примеру `body`, элементу новый `span`.

Пример кода:

```js
var elem =  document.getElementsByClassName('str')[0]; // берем див
var str = elem.innerText; // берем его текст
var symbols = str.split(""); // разбиваем на массив символов
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]; // берем элемент body

symbols.forEach(function(item, i, arr) { // в цикле по всем 
  var span = document.createElement('span'); // создаем span
  span.innerHTML = item; // задаем содержимое span
  body.appendChild(span); // прикрепляем к body
});

//elem.remove(); // удалить наш див
elem.innerHTML = ''; // или убрать из дива текст
```

```html
<div class="str">Шла Саша по шоссе и сосала сушку</div>
```

Обращу внимание на некоторые нюансы. Если будем новые элементы `span` цеплять к нашему `div class="str"`, а в конце удалим этот див через `remove()`, то вместе с ним удалятся и его дочерние элементы. Поэтому в комментарии предложил два варианта: замена содержимого дива или удаление дива и прикреплял новое к `body`

По вашему коду: функция `wrap` помещает заданное содержимое вокруг выбранных элементов (как бы "обертывая" их) - то есть будет выглядеть как-то не так, как хотелось бы. Можно немного изменить код, заменив `wrap` на `append`. Пример кода:

```js
str = $(".str").text().split(''); // берем наш текст и в массив
$(".str").text(''); // делаем пустой див

$.each(str, function() { // идем по массиву
  // добавляем к диву наши символы в span
  $(".str").append('<span class="style">' + this + '</span>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="str">Шла Саша по шоссе и сосала сушку</div>
```

Comment: да вот примерно так же в вопросе попробовал, а почему просто each не работает?

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, потому что не правильно написали. Вот так нужно: `$.each(str, function(i)...`

Comment: Спасибо)
а с помощью метода wrap все-таки как то можно?
просто на jquery мне понятнее чем на js.
Выходит мне нужно: обернуть последовательно элементы в тег span с какими-то дополнительными атрибутами (class, data, не важно), а потом все их состыковать в одной переменной, и эту переменную вставить в блок с классом .str
или хотя бы просто состыковать все в одной переменной, а уж как заменить содержимое дива на нашу переменную я знаю

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, а вы просто `append` на `wrap` замените, вот вам и будет с его помощью. Визуально будет так же, но получится вложенность из кучи `span`, а в `append`  они идут друг за другом - последовательно. Я про это имел в виду в ответе.

Comment: Спасибо добавил еще один ответ с понятным мне вариантом))

Answer (score 4):

split работает.

```js
let str = "Шла Саша по шоссе и сосала сушку";
console.log(str.split(''))
```

Еще можно разбить с помощью spread оператора:

```js
let str = "Шла Саша по шоссе и сосала сушку";
((...args) => {console.log(args)})(...str)
```

Кроме того можно просто перебрать все символы в цикле, без всяких split и spread:

```js
let str = "Шла Саша по шоссе и сосала сушку";
for(let char of str) console.log(char);
```

UP:

Имея на руках массив символов, полученный вышеописанным способом, можно легко обернуть каждый из них в нужный тег.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('.str');
div.innerHTML = div.innerText.split('').reduce( (res, char) => `${res}<span>${char}</span>`, '')

// Более развернутый и понятный вариант:
const div2 = document.querySelector('.str2');
let str = div2.innerText;
let chars = str.split('');
let chars_in_span = chars.map(char => `<span>${char}</span>`);
let new_html = chars_in_span.join('');
div2.innerHTML = new_html;
```

```css
span{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="str">Шла Саша по шоссе и сосала сушку</div>

<div class="str2">Шла Саша по шоссе и сосала сушку</div>
```

Comment: уточнил вопрос, посvотрите пожалуйста, не понял как обернуть отдельные буквы в тег <span>

Answer (score 1):

Родил понятный мне вариант из предложенных выше ответов

```js
str = $(".str").text().split('');
modstr = "";
$.each(str, function(i) {
  modstr = modstr + '<span class="style">' + str[i] + '</span>';
});
$(".str").html(modstr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="str">Шла Саша по шоссе и сосала сушку</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

можно сделать с помошью split/join или regexp replace:

```js
var string="Шла Саша по шоссе и сосала сушку";
//вариант 1
console.log('%c<span class="style">' + string.split('').join('</span><span class="style">') + '</span>', 'color: red' );
//вариант 1
console.log('%c' + string.replace(/(.)/g, '<span class="style">$1</span>'), 'color: blue');
```